# Create a rectangle net/list from 2D Points in python

Tags: python, mesh, point-clouds, points, square

I have a series of points that are to be sorted into adjacent squares so that a mesh is created.

is there maby anything comparable to the Delaunay triangulation?

[Picture from input points in blue and goal in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLrkX.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points_2D = np.array([[2,2],[3,2],[5,2],[7,2],[8,2],[10,2],[2,4],[3,5],[5,4],[7,3],[8,4],[10,5],[2,7],[4,7],[5,7],[6,7],[8,6],[9,7],])

def find_rectangle(points):
    pass
    # return somthing like np.array([rectangle_number][
    # [x,y],
    # [x,y],
    # [x,y],
    # [x,y],
    # ])

#points_2D = find_rectangle(points_2D)

plt.scatter(points_2D[:,0], points_2D[:,1])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hint: two adjacent triangles form a quadrilateral. If you run Delaunay and the resulting number of triangles is even, you can merge adjacent triangles into quadrilaterals.

Comment: Also "rectangle" is really not the correct word here. Rectangles have four right angles. Your quadrilaterals will typically have no right angles.

Answer (score 2):

Apologies for the incomplete answer and the lack of an explanation. (I have an appointment.)

This code prints a set of points for each rectangle but NOT in the correct order:

```
import numpy as np
import  itertools

points_2D = np.array([[2,2],[3,2],[5,2],[7,2],[8,2],[10,2],[2,4],[3,5],[5,4],[7,3],[8,4],[10,5],[2,7],[4,7],[5,7],[6,7],[8,6],[9,7],])

def rectangles(x1, x2, s1, s2):
    inter = s1.intersection(s2)
    if len(inter) > 1:
        comb = list(itertools.combinations(inter, 2))
        for c in comb:
            prod = itertools.product([x1, x2], list(c))
            res = [list(p) for p in prod]
            print(res)

def find_rectangle(points):
    psorted = points[points[:,0].argsort()]
    px = list(np.unique(psorted[:,0]))
    ypoints = np.split(psorted[:,1], np.unique(psorted[:, 0], return_index=True)[1][1:])
    sets = [set(list(arr)) for arr in ypoints]
    for i in range(len(px)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(px)):
            rectangles(px[i], px[j], sets[i], sets[j])

find_rectangle(points_2D)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 2], [2, 4], [5, 2], [5, 4]]
[[2, 2], [2, 7], [5, 2], [5, 7]]
[[2, 4], [2, 7], [5, 4], [5, 7]]
[[2, 2], [2, 4], [8, 2], [8, 4]]
[[3, 2], [3, 5], [10, 2], [10, 5]]
[[5, 2], [5, 4], [8, 2], [8, 4]]
```

The correct order for th2 first line above is:

```
[[2, 2], [2, 4], [5, 4], [5, 2]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, i learn a lot from your code! I plot the output here https://i.stack.imgur.com/URgiH.png . But it was correct i mean quadrilaterals and search for a net, so no are is used multiple times.